# Approximation of trig and polynomial function

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, approximation

Find the smallest value of n for which $\frac{n}{\pi}\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) \gt 0.999$

Not really sure where to start with this. The answer is 41. The question is from the Cambridge Y12 Ext-1 3U HSC textbook, exercise 9A Q20 b)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us how much calculus you've had. (Sorry, those Cambridge codes are over my head.) Where I grew up, in a small country in Eastern Europe, a long time ago, during communism, this would have been learnt in highschool. Later, in the U.S., I saw that the same would be taught in graduate courses at University.

So: $\sin x \approx  x - \frac{x^3}6$ (Taylor series expansion). From this, heuristically, you get $\frac{\sin x}x \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}6$, and then you can prove rigorously that $\frac{\sin x}{x} > 1 - \frac{x^2}6$ for small, positive values of $x$. Now you want $n$ so that $x := \frac{\pi}n$ satisfies $\frac{x^2}6 < 0.001$, and solving for this gives $n > 40.55$ or so. Now, one would also need to show that $n = 40$ won't do, because we only used an inequality in the first place, not an equality. If you are allowed to use an electronic calculator for that, that's fine, but otherwise I don't know how one would prove that (only with pencil and paper).

Answer (score 0):

Do we know that:
$\sin x \approx x - \frac {x^3}{6} = x(1-\frac {x^2}{6})$

$\sin \frac {\pi}{n}= (1-0.001)\frac {\pi}n$

$(\frac {\pi}{n})^2 \approx 0.006\\
n \approx \frac {\pi}{\sqrt {0.006}}\\
n \approx 40.6$

$41$ would be the smallest $n\in N$

$x(1-\frac{x^2}{6})<\sin x<x(1-\frac{x^2}{6} +\frac{x^4}{120})$

$1-\frac{x^2}{6} + \frac {x^4}{120}= 1-0.001\\
x^4 - 20 x^2 + 0.12 = 0\\
x^2 = 10 - \sqrt {100-12}$

$0.0060018<(\frac {\pi}{n})^2 < 0.006\\
\frac {\pi}{\sqrt {0.0060018}}<(\frac {\pi}{n})^2 < \frac {\pi}{\sqrt {0.006}}$

$40.5517<n<40.5577$

Comment: The very last step is dubious at best; there is no way that this argument shows that $n = 40$ will not work.

Comment: $x - \frac {x}{6} <\sin x$ so we can rule out $n = 40$  What is still dubious is that $n = 41$ is big enough.

Comment: Nope. What we know is that $1 - \frac{x^2}6 > 0.999$ if $n > 40.6$, so $n  =41$ is fine. We also know that $n = 40$ will NOT do for that inequality; but since $\frac{\sin x}x$ is *greater* than that expression, we **don't** know that $n = 40$ won't do for $\frac{\sin x}x$. (Note that your expressions are incorrect in the Comment, but I understand what you meant and fixed them here.)

Comment: @mathguy is that satisfactory?

Comment: Yep, that should suffice.